# How Can I use Wrapper Pattern to add additional methods to sealed class?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.0

I would like to ask you how can I get a method like GetAllActiveProjects(). I use Trimble.Connect.Desktop.Api. My class actually look like below:

```
{
    public class TrimbleConnectWrapper : ITrimbleConnectWrapper
    {
        private TrimbleConnectDesktopClient _NonManagedInstance;

        public TrimbleConnectWrapper()
        {
            _NonManagedInstance = new TrimbleConnectDesktopClient();
        }

        public async Task<List<Project>> GetAllActiveProjects()
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

What should I begin with in this task ? And whether 'async Task' is the right operation for this list of current projects in my library ? Does this TrimbleConnectWrapper class is written good as a wrapper pattern ? My main goal is to create a new method that will contain a list of projects existing in my library in trimbleconnect application on desktop (same library is located in web service https://web.connect.trimble.com/projects).

I was looking for answers to my questions above, but did not find a clear answers. If you would like to answer me for some of my questions, I will be satisfied.

Comment: _"What should I begin with in this task ?"_ What do you mean exactly?

Comment: _"And whether 'async Task' is the right operation for this list of current projects in my library ?"_ It depends. Is `TrimbleConnectDesktopClient`'s API async? Would it be reasonable to stream an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IAsyncEnumerable` ? We cannot know that.

Comment: And in general: `_NonManagedInstance` should be `readonly`. And if you want to Unit Test your wrapper, you better Inject the `TrimbleConnectDesktopClient` instance into the ctor. And lastly, if `TrimbleConnectDesktopClient` implements `IDisposable`, the wrapper should do so, too, most probably.

Comment: Thank's Fildor, you were right in your suspicions. I implemented IDisposable, injected `TrimbleConnectDesktopClient`, and yes changed my Task to void method, its not required to be async here. Can you explain me what is the way to body of the GetAllActiveProjects ? How can i refer to them ? Any idea?

Comment: I mean, I have 2 projects in library. And i would like to get them visible here in code...

Comment: I am not familiar with that library and client, so I cannot help with that. If you want to _return_ the references to the `Project`s, you need to return some sort of Collection of them. If you just want to manipulate them here, you can keep void.